# How to sum a infinite convergent series that has a term from the end (infinity)

Tags: convergence-divergence, summation

From my physical problem, I ended up having a sum that looks like the following. It is a follow up from the question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4594224/how-to-sum-a-infinite-divergent-series-that-has-a-term-from-the-end-infinity).

$$ S_N(\omega) = \sum_{q = 1}^{N-1} \left(1 - \frac{q}{N}\right) \exp{\left(-\frac{q^2\sigma^2}{2}\right)} \cos{\left(\left(\mu  - \omega\right)q\right)} $$

I want to know what is the sum when $N \to \infty$. Here, $\omega$ is where this is computed and $\mu$ and $\sigma$ are constants. Can this be reduced to an expression (a function of variables $\omega$, $\mu$ and $\sigma$) ?

I have proceeded like the following to show that this function indeed converges when $N \to \infty$.

$$ S_N(\omega) - S_{N - 1}(\omega) = (1 - \frac{N-1}{N}) \exp{\left(-\frac{(N-1)^2\sigma^2}{2}\right)} \cos{\left(\left(\mu  - \omega\right)(N-1)\right)} + \sum_{q = 1}^{N-2} q(\frac{1}{N-1} - \frac{1}{N}) \exp{\left(-\frac{q^2\sigma^2}{2}\right)} \cos{\left(\left(\mu  - \omega\right)q\right)} $$

This difference goes to $0$ if $N \to \infty$.

Comment: A consecutive difference going to 0 does not mean a series converges e.g. $a_n=\frac{1}{n}$ has a none convergent sum.

Comment: Note, this isn't a series, because $(1-q/N)$ depends on the value $N.$

Comment: Also, $ S_N(\omega) - S_{N - 1}(\omega)$ is the difference of a sum of $N-1$ terms and $N-2$ terms. So your formula there is wrong - you've included a term for $N-1$ from both sums.

Comment: Ah yes! I will change it.

Comment: I have changed the expression for the difference between $S_N$ and $S_{N-1}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Showing that $S_N(\omega) - S_{N-1}(\omega) \to 0$ is not sufficient to prove $S_N(\omega)$ has a limit as $N \to \infty$. (It is necessary though, i.e. if the differences didn't approach 0 then there would be no hope of the limit existing.)

Anyway, your sequence of functions does converge unless $\sigma = 0$. To prove convergence, first write
$$\begin{align}
S_N(\omega) &= \sum_{q=1}^{N-1} \exp\left(-\frac{q^2 \sigma^2}{2}\right) \cos((\mu-\omega)q) - \frac 1 N \sum_{q=1}^{N-1} q \exp\left(-\frac{q^2 \sigma^2}{2}\right) \cos((\mu-\omega)q) \\
&= A_N(\omega) - \frac 1 N B_N(\omega)
\end{align}$$
where I'm just defining $A_N(\omega$ and $B_N(\omega)$ as shorthand for those two big summations. Let $A_\infty$ and $B_\infty$ be the "infinite versions" of those sums. Then to show $S_N$ converges, it's sufficient to show $A_\infty(\omega)$ and $B_\infty(\omega)$ both converge. We'll do that by showing these series are [absolutely convergent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_convergence).

For $B_\infty$, we have:
$$\begin{align}
|B_\infty(\omega)| &\le \sum_{q=1}^\infty \left| q \exp\left(-\frac{q^2 \sigma^2}{2}\right) \cos((\mu-\omega)q) \right| \\
&\le \sum_{q=1}^\infty q \exp\left(-\frac{q^2 \sigma^2}{2}\right)
\end{align}$$
**Assuming $\sigma \not = 0$**, this last series converges by the [integral test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20the%20integral%20test,as%20the%20Maclaurin%E2%80%93Cauchy%20test.) (using the substitution $u = q^2$). Or depending on your level of confidence with asymptotic behavior, it might just be really obvious that it converges because $e^{-q^2} \to 0$ way faster than $q \to \infty$. Anyway, this shows that $B_\infty(\omega)$ is a convergence series.

For $A_\infty$ we do a similar check:
$$\begin{align}
|A_\infty(\omega)| &\le \sum_{q=1}^\infty \left|  \exp\left(-\frac{q^2 \sigma^2}{2}\right) \cos((\mu-\omega)q) \right| \\
&\le \sum_{q=1}^\infty  \exp\left(-\frac{q^2 \sigma^2}{2}\right)
\end{align}.$$
This final series is the same as we got with $B_\infty$ except this time there's no factor of $q$. That means this version is strictly smaller than the series we used to bound $B_\infty$, and that one converged absolutely, so this one does too. Therefore $A_\infty$ is a convergent series too.

In summary, we've written $S_N(\omega) = A_N(\omega) - \frac 1 N B_N(\omega)$. As long as $\sigma \not = 0$, we showed $A_N(\omega)$ and $B_N(\omega)$ converge to some values $A_\infty(\omega)$ and $B_\infty(\omega)$ respectively, so $S_N(\omega)$ converges to $A_\infty(\omega)$ too (since the $\frac 1 N$ factor kills the contribution from $B_\infty(\omega)$).

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. It gave me a lot of perspective. I will try to implement.

Comment: One more comment. I forgot to mention that for my physical problem $\sigma > 0$. So, your formulation is perfectly suited for the problem.